# Where does Elastic-Search live on my Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, elasticsearch

[picture of the file path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiVPW.png)

Where is this file path?

/usr/local/var/elasticsearch/....

I need to get into my elasticsearch files and Mac just put them in this directory.

Comment: Can you specify how did you install elasticsearch ? like as a dmg or though zip or as a service?

Comment: I figured it out, all I did was FInder/Go/Go to Folder but it was weird because installing with brew made it go to /usr/local/var but a pure zip download was a true enclosed folder in my downloads.